# How to refernce groovy script in Jenkins Email-Ext

Tags: jenkins, groovy, email-ext

I need to trigger email notification if groovy script output is true,
I did this by added a Script - After Build Trigger to Email-Ext triggers and put my script as `${SCRIPT, template="myscript.groovy"}` in Script - After Build -> Groovy Script block, 
after save this configuration I got this error.

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: SCRIPT @ line 1, column 3.
   ${SCRIPT, template="myscript.groovy"}
     ^

1 error
```

I got this from Email-ext site

> Use the script token with the template parameter equal to your
>   template filename, or in addition the script parameter equal to the
>   custom script name. For example, if the template filename is
>   foobar.template, the email content would look like this ${SCRIPT,
>   template="foobar.template"}.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Scriptcontent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, it turns out that that block isn't for script reference, is for script, I put my Groovy Script in that block and it worked.

Comment: Seems like this block (Script - After Build -> Groovy Script ) is for the script content, not the script reference, as far as I know, there is no way to reference the script by the name, you will have to put the script directly in the block.

Comment: Figured it out:
 def emailSubject = "${currentBuild.result}: ${currentBuild.projectName} - Build ${currentBuild.number}"
                    emailext body:  '${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="html"}', subject: emailSubject , to: '${EMAIL_TO}', mimeType: 'text/html'